# How to find website pages are wordpress or not

Tags: wordpress

My old colleagues created one website. They were used wordpress for some pages. I dont know what are the pages build from wordpress , what are the pages build from NOrmal HTML.

How to find this

More Are tools there for find wordpress from full websites. I want find some pages are wordpress or not

Comment: View source of the page and find the wp-content directory for css/images.

Comment: All the pages have that theme URL. I think. they were use theme plugin for all pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the source code of the website and check if you find this tag:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.8.2" />
```

If you don't know how to look for it, you can use this other website that will check (with it's own methods) if the website is working and will tell you if the website was built with Wordpress:

http://ismyblogworking.com/